# Invalid signature error opening document got via docusign api

Tags: docusignapi

We have downloaded a signed document from Docusign via the SOAP API and uploaded the same on our content server.While downloading this document from our content server and opening the same via Adobe we get a invalid signature error with reason as "Digitally Verifiable PDF downloaded from www.docusign.com".We have added the docusign certificate trust as well but that does not help either.Is there anything missing?
Adding more details....
We are currently using a GET call on the get documents rest api namely
v2/accountid/envelopes/envelopeId/documents/combined Since we have a number of documents we are using the "combined" parameter.Could this be causing it?Should we say certificate="true" explicitly?

Comment: This needs more detail describing how the documents should be signed, whether some documents succeed, code sample etc

Comment: Try opening the signed document after retrieving it from SOAP API, instead of opening it from your content server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to open the downloaded document from Docusign via the SOAP API before uploading to your server and check if it is valid or not. if it is valid then that doesn't make sense.

If it is not valid then most probably the certificate used to sign the document is invalid. you might give us a screenshot of the details of the error in the signature panel in adobe software. It might give us an idea why the signature is invalid.

Comment: We have now switched to a REST API call as updated above i.e GET call on the get documents rest api namely ...v2/accountid/envelopes/envelopeId/documents/combined